# infinite sum corresponds to infinite product in book Norris

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

On page 72 of the book Markov Chains by Norris, they state that, for $0<\lambda_n<\infty \;\; \forall n$:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/ \lambda_n  = \infty$

implies

$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+1/\lambda_n)=\infty$.

How can this be seen? I tried taking logarithms but that does not seem to help.

Is the reverse statement also true?

Comment: Hint: Note that for positive $a,b$, $(1+a)(1+b) = 1 + a + b + ab > 1 + a + b$. Try to use this observation to show inductively that for each natural $k \ge 2$, $\prod_{n=1}^k (1 + \lambda_n^{-1}) > 1 + \sum_{n=1}^k \lambda_n^{-1}$. Now taking the limit as $k \uparrow \infty$ gives you the proposition.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. I was wondering, is the reverse of this statement also true? It appears that this proof cannot be used in the other direction.

Comment: Indeed, the above proof only works in one direction. For the converse, note that for $x > 0$, $x > \ln(1+x)$ (to prove this note that the derivative of $x - \ln (1+x) $ is $\frac{x}{1+x} >0$, and that $0 - \ln(1+0)= 0$). Now, $ \sum_1^k \lambda_n^{-1} > \sum_1^k \ln(1+\lambda_n^{-1}) = \ln \left(\prod_1^k (1 + \lambda_n^{-1}) \right) $, and taking limits does the trick.